# comparar datos recibidos desde uart en un avr

Tags: c, arduino, atmel

Estoy  intentando comparar un dato ingresado desde el monitor serial, para que mi microcontrolador haga "x"  función. Pero al parecer no funciona incluso utilizando la función  strcmp.

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "USART.h"/*esta es mi biblioteca para  uart */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void) {
    static char buf[1026];
    uart_Init();
    DDRB |=1<<7;
    while(1) {
            
        uart_get(buf);/*funcion para obtener datos */
        if(strcmp(buf,"on")==0){

            printstring("encendido\0");/*funcion para enviar datos*/
        }


    }
 }
```

**el siguiente bloque de codigo pertenece al codigo de la blibioteca uart la cual fue creada siguiendo los ejemplos contenedios el los datasheet de atmel**

```c
void uart_Tx(char data){
/* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
//
UDR0 = data;


}


static char uart_Rx(void) {
    

while (!(UCSR0A & (1<< RXC0))); /* espera hasta que exista algun dato */
return (UDR0);
   
}

void printstring(char *mystring){
    unsigned char i=0;
    while (mystring[i]){
        uart_Tx(mystring[i]);
        i++;
    }
    
    i=0;
}

void uart_get(char buf[]){
    uint8_t bufIdx = 0;
    static char c;

    // while received character is not carriage return
    // and end of buffer has not been reached
    do{
         // receive character
        c = uart_Rx();

        // store character in buffer
        buf[bufIdx] = c;
        bufIdx ++;

    }
   while((bufIdx <= 256) && (c != '\n'));
    // ensure buffer is null terminated
   buf[bufIdx] = 0;
   bufIdx=0;
}
```

en pocas palabras los datos son recibidos desde el uart y almacenado en un vector denominado buf,dicho vector de manera posterior se envia a la funcion printstring para poder ser mostrado en el monitor serial

Comment: Y la pregunta lógica es ... ¿ Que recibes en `buf` ? ¿ Es una cadena, terminada en `0` ?

Comment: Hay muchas librerias "uart.h". ¿Cual específicamente estas usando?

Comment: en buf estoy recibiendo el dato enviado desde el monitor serial el cual es direccionado por medio de un puntero

Comment: Con la nula información que aportas, lo único que te puedo decir es que uses `strncmp( buf, "on", 2 )`

Comment: @Trauma  ya agregué  mas info a la pregunta

Comment: @CandidMoe estoy utilizando una biblioteca personal

Comment: Seria interesante que imprimieras el contenido de `buf` inmediatamente que retornas de `uart_get`. También imprime el largo, por si contiene caracteres no representables. Es para descartar que estes recibiendo caracteres indeseados.

Comment: @CandidMoe Inmediantamente al hacer que imprima  muestra la cadena de texto en forma correcta